# can't get relation's name via listdata

Tags: yii

I am not sure why I can't get the columns from my other tables via my relations. I was thinking is it because of my scope? After i had a default scope in my models, everything seems to be out of place, even if i use resetscope() at some places. Some sections I can't get to my relation columns; when that happens, I'd have to use `Model::model->findbypk(n)->name`.. that doesn't look pretty.

the id shows if i don't have the relations, but the name is blank when i put the relation name.

```
 CHtml::listData(Model::model()->findAll(),'product_id','main.product_name'),
```

my model defaultscope is pretty basic:

```
return array(
    'condition'=>'store_id1=:store_id OR store_id2=:store_id' ,
    'params' => array(':store_id' => $store_id)
);
```

Comment: Have you tried Model::model()->with('main')->findAll() ?

Comment: You're welcome. I submit the answer for others and it would be great if you mark the answer as accept. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the way you use your model like below:

```
Model::model()->with('main')->findAll();
```

Comment: actually it didn't work.. it only works for the store's own products, but not retrieving other stores. :/